# How to change the color of a cell, based on values of 2 cells

Tags: excel

Updated info..First of all, I'm having a hard time formatting my info, in this forum, to make sense. Lol.

Here is the more specific question.
Based on the value input for Likelihood(Column F) and Impact (Column G), I would like the color to reflect the  Risk Level (Column H)

Here is the  number/color combination

Column F is Likelihood_  Column G is Impact _ Column H is Risk Level/Color

Column F= 1, Column G= 1-4,  Column H= green

Column F= 2, Column G= 1-3, Column H= green

Column F= 3, Column G= 1-2, Column H= green

Column F= 4, Column G   1,  Column H=green

Column F= 5, Column G   1,  Column H=green

---

Column F= 1, Column G   5,  Column H=yellow

Column F= 2, Column G 4-5,  Column H=yellow

Column F= 3, Column G 3-4,  Column H=yellow

Column F= 4, Column G 2-3,  Column H=yellow

Column F= 5, Column G  2,   Column H=yellow

---

Column F= 3, Column G  5,   Column H=Red

Column F= 4, Column G  4-5, Column H=Red

Column F= 5, Column G  3-5,   Column H=Red

Comment: "If column F is <6 and column F <4`...what? Can you clarify this part please?

Comment: To handle multiple condition in conditional formatting, you could use something like: `=AND(F1<6;G1<-4)`

Comment: You can use conditional formatting, based on a highlighing rule, based on a formula. Does that work?

Comment: I've added some specific language to  my question. Hopefully, this helps